# About Code Access Security, What is mobile code?

Tags: c#

Recently I read a [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/930b76w0%28VS.71%29.aspx) about Code Access Security. I am absolutely new about this issue.
There is one sentence,

> To help protect computer systems from malicious mobile code, to allow
>   code from unknown origins to run with protection, and to help prevent
>   trusted code from intentionally or accidentally compromising security,
>   the .NET Framework provides a security mechanism called code access
>   security.

What is mobile code? How mobile code run?

And another scene, just imagine, I have a winform application  running, and this application will download a dll from internet. My problem is, is the application able to run the dll?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_code

Comment: Code Access Security is now upgraded to Security Model . The basic idea is to identify critical parts of code and non trustable parts of code and allow permissions to run appropriately. eg. if your DLL is not expected to view folders on the client , it should restrict those sort of permissions

Comment: @RameezAhmedSayad As you said, if my DLL is not expected to view folders on the client. My question is, how .Net Runtime knows that the DLL doesn't have that permission? Where is the permission info stroes?